# Create composite index across tables

Tags: mysql

I am doing a `JOIN` and would like to speed it up by creating a composite index between the joining tables:

```
SELECT * FROM catalog_product_entity AS p 
INNER JOIN catalog_product_flat_1 AS cpf 
ON cpf.entity_id = p.entity_id`
```

in a way similar to this:

```
create index foo on catalog_product_flat_1 (entity_id,catalog_product_entity.entity_id);
```

The approach above generates a syntax error. What is the correct wat to create a composite index that uses cross-table columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When joining two tables, the server has to look up the information of one record on one side of the join in the table of the other side. Therefore, an index across two tables does not help in this regard. The index is only useful on that side of the join that is actually looked up.

**Consequently, an index spanning multiple tables is not possible.**

The query planner takes this into account and resolves the join condition in a way which uses the most efficient lookup. In your example, the query planner might first check for an index on `cpf.entity_id` and `p.entity_id` if there is no index, it will search the smaller table and try other optimizations. MySql's [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) can provide further insight.

Comment: I don't even think it's possible to create an index that spans across multiple tables, is it?

Comment: thanks. I have both indexes, but still, join takes 0.2s , because the two tables have 200k entries. is there a way to speed up the join? probably temporary tables?

Comment: I assume you are actually `SELECT`ing all 200k rows? I don't think the `JOIN` is the problem. However, you could check out `EXPLAIN`. See update...